# Show that z-axis of Lorenz equations is invariant

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

Given Lorenz equations
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= \sigma(y-x)\\
\dot{y} &= rx - y- xz\\
\dot{z} &= xy - bz
\end{align}
suppose $x(0)=0=y(0)$.
Prove that $x(t)=0=y(t)$ for all $t \ge 0$.

Intuitively, I can see that this is true. But I am not sure how to give a rigorous proof.
Could you give some hints or references to related concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(0,0,z_0 e^{-bt})$ is a solution with initial data $(0,0,z_0)$, and the solution to the initial value problem is unique by the Picard–Lindelöf theorem.

More conceptually, on the $z$ axis the vector field equals $(0,0,-bz)$, which is tangent to the $z$-axis. Therefore the $z$ axis is invariant.